# Error installing unf_ext -v '0.0.6' when run bundle install in Windows 64bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

Environment: Windows 10 (64bit) + Ruby 2.2.3p173

I also have downloaded and installed Rails Installer  (from http://railsinstaller.org/en) + run "gem install rails" as well and it was success
The situation is when I run "bundle install" in cmd, the processes stop at the line

"Installing unf_ext 0.0.6 with native extension" as shown below[image: Error when run bundle install]

I also tried to run "gem install unf_ext" already but what I got is the lastest version which the error still appear. Also "gem install unf_ext -v 0.0.6" as well, it didnt help to clear the error.

I have try to search on google in many website but mostly the solutions are for iOS which is not my current OS, Windows 10 64 bits.

Comment: Could you run `gem update --system` then try installing again?

Comment: I have tried that already but it said the system is up to date so I run bundle install again and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, most likely you're going to have to update to version `0.0.7` or preferably `0.0.7.1`.

If that's not possible then you will probably have to use `Ruby 2.0.0 32-bit` to use `unf_ext` since the last fat binary was released before `Ruby 2.1.5` was released therefore couldn't have been built for `Ruby 2.1.5` compatibility and there's only a fat binary for `32-bit` in that version. See:

https://rubygems.org/gems/unf_ext/versions

To update it use `gem unf_ext, '~> 0.0.7.1'` in your `Gemfile`.